# disable blue background and highlight only the text in html

Tags: html

I can disable the content selection of any webpage using the code below which works well.

```
<div 
 style="-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;" 
 unselectable="on"
 onselectstart="return false;" 
 onmousedown="return false;">
    Cannot select me
</div>
```

Image showing text selection is given below :

[image]

My question is:

- How can i disable blue background and highlight only the text that i select from any webpage?

Second part of the question moved to [ux.stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/80883/why-the-browsers-take-shades-of-blue-while-selecting).

Comment: I guess 2nd and 3rd belong to UX.SE.

Comment: kk then .let me move it over there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [::selection](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-selection) CSS pseudo-element will help you, apply it to `body` or `html` like;

```
body::selection {
    background-color:transparent;
    color:#0000FF;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z974juvb/)

Comment: I still need to add with vendor prefix `-moz-selection` for Firefox browser. Not sure why.